# How do I make my Backgroundtask start on Startup?

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a background task, that is currently launched whenever my application starts and it is currently not running. But I would like it to also start on startup, if that's possible. I have looked into the triggers, and there appears to be none that can make it start on startup. According to MSDN there is a way to make a startup task, but they don't say how to convert my current task into a startup task. Is that even possible:

```
<uap5:Extension Category="windows.startupTask">
  <uap5:StartupTask
    TaskId="MyStartupId"
    Enabled="true"
    DisplayName="Background-Keyboard task" />
</uap5:Extension> //Documentation

<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Background.BackgroundTask">
  <BackgroundTasks>
    <Task Type="systemEvent" />
  </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension> //My task
```

I currently initiate my task like this:

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Background.BackgroundTask";

ApplicationTrigger _AppTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
builder.SetTrigger(_AppTrigger);


builder.Register();

await _AppTrigger.RequestAsync();
```

Edit: My reason for wanting this:

My app provides a background service that can be toggled on and off. It should be running all the time, and that does work after I open the app. But it should not be necessary to open it every time the device is restarted - which is currently the case, and I want to add the possibility to let the background service start at startup. Ideally I would also want to keep the current way of launching it - via `_AppTrigger.RequestAsync();`, so my enable/disable slider keeps working.

Comment: @HansPassant Will the task only trigger when it is not already running? If I hybernate a pc for example, the task will conitnue running after I wake it up. So does this not count as a SessionConnected?

Comment: @HansPassant that makes me unable to use my current trigger

Comment: The `StartupTask` class is used to configure your app to start at log-in. Please describe your actual usage scenario to see if you really need to use `StartupTask`.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I have updated my post to explain my usage scenario.

Comment: The background task is controlled by a separate process (backgroundtaskhost.exe), not your app. It doesn't always be running. It only will start to execute when some conditions are met or trigger is triggered.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Yes, I currently trigger it with await _AppTrigger.RequestAsync();. I would like to add a trigger to add it at startup. Could I use a StartupTask to start my background task this way? Or can I add a second trigger that fires when the system is started somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have already indicated, you should use a SystemTrigger of TriggerType=SessionConnected to have the task start when the user logs on. You can still also use the ApplicationTrigger to trigger the task from your foreground app whenever that is needed. You can have two or more triggers with the same entry point, triggering the same task implementation. In fact, in order to make this scenario complete you also want to add a SystemTriggerType=PowerChanged trigger to cover power/sleep state changes.

Comment: Alright, but I do need to register a new task, because each task can only have one trigger, correct?

Also, from an earlier comment: Will the task only trigger when it is not already running? If I hybernate a pc for example, the task will conitnue running after I wake it up. So does this not count as a SessionConnected?

Comment: Yes, you need to register them per trigger, but they can have the same entry point. The triggers will fire whenever their respective condition is true. If the task is already running you will want to manage that case in your code with some kind of singleton pattern if you want to ensure you have only one instance running at a time.

Comment: To answer the wake-up from hibernate question: you also want to trigger on SystemTriggerType=PowerChange to handle that case. I have built a sample for exactly what you are trying to do here, but never got around to publishing it. I'll see if I can clean it up soon and share it here, but with the info provided here you should be able to get going.